# line vector in conservative vector field. inconsistent results.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Studying a problem related to line integral in vector field in conservative field.

$\vec{F} = (2xy + z^3)\hat{\text{i}} + (x^2)\hat{\text{j}} + (3xz^2)\hat{\text{k}}$

$\phi = x^2y +xz^3$

$\vec{F} = \nabla \phi$

find line integral from point (1,-2,1) to (3,1,4)

---

here's the solution the textbook gives:

$d\vec{r} = dx\hat{\text{i}} + dy\hat{\text{j}} + dz\hat{\text{k}}$

$\text{work done} = \int \limits^{P_2}_{P_1} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}$

$\text{work done} = \int \limits^{P_2}_{P_1} (2xy+z^3)dx + (x^2)dy + (3xz^2)dz$

**now for the part i don't understand:**

$\text{work done} = \int \limits^{P_2}_{P_1} d(x^2y+xz^3) = ... = 202$

**how did they go from dx and dy to d(...)? and what does d(...) syntax mean?**

when i try to do this integral i get:

[image: work]

which is off by a factor of 2... and not in agreement with the result found using just the scalar potential...

$\phi(3,1,4) - \phi(1,-2,1) = 202$

Comment: When integrating a multi-parameter function f(x,y,z), it is a requirement that the limits only change the parameter under integration, and all other parameters are held constant.   $\int \limits^{(A,b,c)}_{(a,b,c)}f(x,y,z) dx = \int \limits^{A}_{a} f(x,y,z)dx$ however, $\int \limits^{(A,B,C)}_{(a,b,c)}\bigg(f(x,y,z) dx + g(x,y,z)dy + h(x,y,z)dz \bigg) \ne \int \limits^{A}_{a} f(x,y,z)dx + \int \limits^{B}_{b} f(x,y,z)dy +  \int \limits^{C}_{c} f(x,y,z)dz$

Answer (score 1):

The syntax means,

$$df(x,y,z)=\frac{df}{dx}dx + \frac{df}{dy}dy +\frac{df}{dz}dz$$

So, if $f(x,y,z) =x^2y+xz^3$,

$$d(x^2y+xz^3) = (2xy+z^3)dx + x^2dy + 3xz^2dz$$

Edit:

You were integrating over $x$, $y$ and $z$ independently as if they are unrelated. Specifically, you integrate over $x$ holding $y$ and $z$ constant, which is incorrect. All three variables change simultaneously along the path $\phi$. The factor of 2 is merely an coincidence.

Comment: thanks!  that part makes sense now... its just $\int \limits^{P_2}_{P_1}  d\phi = \phi\bigg|^{P_2}_{P_1}$.   Any ideas why integrating directly without using $\phi$ is off by a factor of 2?  that one kind of bugs me as well...

Comment: @pico - added some explanation in the answer.

Comment: ahh!  that one is tricky...if i understand correctly, its because all three coordinates in the limit  change at the same time... thus, when i distributed the integral over the 3 terms it doesn't work... for instance, the dx term still has z, and y changing in the limits... therefore you can't integrate it with respect to dx because integration by x requires that all other variables are held constant...

Comment: @pico - that is correct. btw, the problem is designed to integrate $d(x^2y+xz^3)$ as a whole. To integrate individually would be very cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

By an easy inspection we get that $\phi(x,y,z)=x^{2}y+z^{3}x$.

It is clear that $\bigtriangledown\,\phi=f$ . Since the field is conservative, we have:

$I=\phi(3,1,4)-\phi(1,-2,1)=202$, if my calculations are correct!!